# Requesting 8MB of heap memory through malloc , but not get allocated

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, malloc

We are trying to convert captured screen image buffer to intermediate before encoding need 8MB of Heap Memory for that using malloc in vc++ , but it returns null. We have available memory in RAM. Any idea on this ?

Comment: Visual C++ `malloc` is a thin wrapper around `HeapAlloc` it may be that the process or dll heap doesn't have enough space. If you need a large allocation [`VirtualAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) may be a better choice as it can do full page or large slab allocations.

Comment: 8MB is not a lot nowadays. Without seeing the code, first guess would be that some of the previously allocated memory is not released, and the app leaks memory until it runs out of it.